# Different Textures for same Level Data

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, assets

The code below shows my Assets class which allows me to load the texture once and call it when I need it globally. If you see that my pack is called house1.pack meaning that there will be more than one house with different art styles. I was wondering if I could achieve a design similar to the popular app Clash Royale with my current code and minor tweaks. I want there to load a different .pack file based on player rank when they are in game. The different houses have the same objects with the same png file names and sizes, but they are just drawn differently.

Thanks,

### Denfeet

```
public class Assets implements Disposable, AssetErrorListener {

public static final String TAG = Assets.class.getName();

public static final Assets instance = new Assets();

private AssetManager assetManager;

public AssetFonts fonts;

public AssetDoor door;
public AssetPlatform platform;
public AssetPlayer player;
public AssetControls controls;

// singleton
private Assets() {
}

public void init(AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
    assetManager.setErrorListener(this);
    assetManager.load("TexturePacker/house1.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();

    TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get("TexturePacker/house1.pack");

    //create game resource objects
    fonts = new AssetFonts();
    door = new AssetDoor(atlas);
    platform = new AssetPlatform(atlas);
    player = new AssetPlayer(atlas);
    controls = new AssetControls(atlas);
}

@Override
public void error(AssetDescriptor asset, Throwable throwable) {
    Gdx.app.error(TAG, "Couldn't load asset '" + asset.fileName + "'", (Exception) throwable);
}

public class AssetFonts {
...
}

public class AssetPlayer {
    ...
}

public class AssetControls {
    ...
}

public class AssetDoor {
...
}

public class AssetPlatform {
...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can load and unload assets at any time. Provided you don't want to use house1.pack anywhere else in your game, you can:

```
assetManager.unload("TexturePacker/house1.pack")
```

to dispose of your house1.pack, then do most of what you have in your init() method to again

```
assetManager.load("TexturePacker/house2.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
assetManager.finishLoading();
//etc
```

Not sure how you'd structure your code, but the above is the idea. Depending on how many assets you're talking about (loading time), you may need a natural transition point (not necessarily a full loading screen). But if you want to change textures from one house to another on the fly, you'd probably want to load them all at once at the beginning and find a different method to swap them.

Comment: Is it possible to have a variable, like an string with the filename, and based on the value of the variable load whichever texture I want at any given time?

Comment: I suppose, but your performance would likely suffer. Depending on how many houses you have and other resources, you could load all your house TextureAtlases initially, your code would have to figure out which one to use to apply to your components. Loading a texture from file in the middle of action could make your game stutter/look bad. Best to load textures ahead of time and not only when you need them. Using many different textures each frame can also affect performance due to frequent binding. Check out https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites